# flowchart representing Structure in C

Tags: c, structure, flowchart

Suppose i have a structure like

```
struct
  {
   char text[20];
   float radius;
   float area;
  }circle[10];
```

how can i represent the above structure using flowchart

Comment: Don't flowcharts describe processes rather than data?

Comment: A flowchart is a type of diagram that represents **an algorithm or process**, but not **data**.

Comment: yes you are right. how can i represent scanf("%s",circle[i].text); in flowchart.

Comment: @insanity, you should edit your question (or delete it and ask a new one), since your comment changes it entirely.

Comment: scanf is still a single operation, not really a process (unless you really care about the internal implementation of reading input from the keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

**You can't:**

**Flowchart** is for representing **algorithms or processes**, but not **data.**

1)    *"...how can i represent scanf("%s",circle[i].text); in flowchart."* (your comment)

The graphical respresentation of it in **flowchart** will look like:

```
A flowchart representation:          More detailed:
             ...                                   ...
              |                                     |
  ____________|___________           _______________|_________________
 /                        \         /                                 \
 |    enter some text     |         |   scanf("%s",circle[i].text);   |
 \________________________/         \_________________________________/
              |                                     |
              |                                     |
             ...                                   ...
```

2) **As for your structure, you don't need its representation:** the structure in the code is very easy to understand:

```
/* How can it be easier to understand? */
struct
{
    char text[20];
    float radius;
    float area;
} circle[10];
```

Look at you structure and you'll be able to see it's "name" (`struct circle`) and variables that it contains (`char text[20];` `float radius;` `float area;`). What can be easier to understand the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Flow charts are not used to represent data structures, they are used to represent  process flows(algorithms).

Your question is not clear enough.  Given the structure you defined above, I will assume you want UML like representation.

Answer (score 0):

Flowcharts represent the flow of control. You can use a subset of the Unified Modelling Language (UML) to represent data and interrelations between objects (e.g. UML Object Diagrams, see [here](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html)), since you can think of a C struct being an public class with public members.

```
+------------------------------+
| circle : array of 10 structs |
+------------------------------+
| text   : array of 20 chars   |
| radius : float               |
| area   : float               |
+------------------------------+
```

Alternatively, you could give the struct a name, and have one box for the struct and one
for the array of 10 structs.